# How to override default spinner behaviour to work as a separate activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-spinner

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to override the default spinner behaviour so instead of it opening a drop down, it opens another activity (perhaps a fragment or maybe even a fullscreen dialog?) and lists all the options as a scrollview.

The best example of this is WhatsApp's country selector.

[image: This is before clicking on the spinner]

[image: This is after clicking on the spinner]

Comment: You do not want a spinner than. You want a `TextView` with a `drawableRight` set an arrow icon.

Comment: You should use fragment with recycler view instead spinner

Comment: It need not be a spinner. You can create a similar layout with textview,bottom border and image at the end. And onclick of that view open another activity containing list. on select you can pass the result to previous activity using onActivityResult callback.